# Before, not replace

Tags: javascript, html, replace

Trying to figure out how should I put a span before my_div_class and not to replace all of it. Now it replaces the div, but I don't want to do it. I assume it's something like :before but have no idea how to use it.

```
<script>
 {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("my_div_class");
  x[0].innerHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000;'>Hello World!<span>";
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("my_div_class");
var html = '<span style="color:#ff0000;">Hello World!<span>';
x[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
```

```html
<div class="my_div_class">Hallo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add the `span` before the current content of the `div`, use:

```
x[0].innerHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000;'>Hello World!</span> " + x[0].innerHTML;
```

Notice that you have several errors in your code:

- You didn't close the `span` tag properly.
- You don't need those curly brackets.
- You may want to add a space at the end of the `span` to separate it from the current content of the `div`.

Try this:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("my_div_class");
x[0].innerHTML = "<span style='color:#ff0000;'>Hello World!</span> " + x[0].innerHTML;
```

```html
<div class="my_div_class">first div</div>
<div class="my_div_class">another div</div>
<div class="my_div_class">yet another div</div>
<div class="my_div_class">second div</div>
<div class="my_div_class">third div</div>
```

Comment: Using innerHTML like this should be avoided, if it can have event handlers.

Comment: @dfsq If else, if else... Could we please stop assuming things? Who said it has event handles? The OP is using it and never mentioned event handles or any other issue. The question is specifically about how to place the new content in front of the current content instead of replacing it, and this answer does exactly that. For a different question, I would've given a different answer, but for this question, that's all what's needed.